# Toggling CSS Class Has No Effect on Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a basic JavaScript drop down menu. I am toggling a class called "show," which displays the drop down content. It will not work - the element stays hidden even after the class is applied.

I imagine I have an error in here somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Help!

```js
  function drop() {
   document.getElementById('content').classList.toggle('show');
  }
```

```css
  .container {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
  }
  .dropdown_btn {
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 20px;
  }
  .dropdown_btn:hover, .dropdown_btn:focus {
   background-color: grey;
  }
  #content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   width: 160px;
  }
  .container a {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
   color: white;
  }
  .container a:hover {
   background-color: #f1f1f1
  }
  .show {
   display: block;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
   <button class="dropdown_btn" onclick="drop()">Menu</button>
   <div id="content">
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have a closed `</ul>` tag but you haven't opened one

Comment: True. Fixed that. It doesn't impact the javascript though. Something is missing

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? Any JavaScript errors? Did you inspect the HTML to see if the class changed? "It doesn't work" is never a good enough description of a problem

Comment: @cale_b are you seriously going after me over that? I thought this site was about helping people...

Answer (score 7):

### The problem is not with your JavaScript, it's with your CSS.

Your `#content` style rule is more specific than your `.show` rule.  When you toggle the `.show` rule on and off, the `#content` rule overrides it and that rule says that `display` should be `none`.

See **[selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** for more information about which selectors will override others. There is also a **[great site](https://specificity.keegan.st/)** that you can test selectors to see what their specificity is. Using that site's "calculator" you can see that an `id` based selector will always override a "class" selector.

[image: ID selector is more specific that class selector.]

The solution is to change the `#content` selector to a class selector, which I've done here (`.menu`). That way, you'll have two class selectors affecting the drop down menu and they will both have the same specificity (the one that will override the other will simply be determined by the last one applied).

```js
function drop() {
  document.getElementById('content').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown_btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown_btn:hover, .dropdown_btn:focus {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* This used to be an id based selector (#content), but that
   type of selector is more specific than a class selector so
   toggling the class selector had no effect. */
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
 width: 160px;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.container a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

/* This is the class that will be toggled on and off.
   Because the CSS rule that hides this menu uses a
   class selector, another class selector can override it. */
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button class="dropdown_btn" onclick="drop()">Menu</button>
   <div id="content" class="menu">
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what you have here works, but I'm going off a w3school lesson that says this should work with normal javascript: 

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: this is what w3school says works: 

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

Comment: @jseabolt the JavaScript was fine. You should do some debugging before asking a question so you can explain what you have tried.

Comment: @J Seabolt You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark this as the answer.